# My '==' operator is not working

Tags: python, equality

Here is the basic problem:

```
test = 24.02000 - 24
print "test: %f" % test
if (test == 0.02):
    print "OK"
```

Output:

```
test: 0.20000
```

"OK" should have been printed out as well.

However if I do this:

```
test = 0.02
print "test: %f" % test
if (test == 0.02):
    print "OK"
```

I get:

```
test: 0.020000  
OK
```

Am I missing something here or is this really a bug?

Comment: Strongly recommend to read this https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: >>> 24.02000 - 24
0.019999999999999574

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to floating point imprecisions since computers deal in base-2 while we deal in base-10:

```
>>> 24.02000 - 24
0.019999999999999574
```

To overcome this problem, you can use **`round`**:

```
test = 24.02000 - 24
print "test: %f" % test
if (round(test, 2) == 0.02):   #round the float to a certain degree of precision and then do the comparison
    print "OK"

[OUTPUT]
test: 0.020000
OK
```

If you want to compare with a higher precision, you can vary the second parameter of `round`:

```
(round(test, 5) == 0.2)
```